# What should I fill in DS-160 current employment section if I am a freelancer for an F1 visa?

Tags: f1-visas, us-visa

I was working in an organisation from last 2.5 years but in October 2018 I left my job to continue with the exam preparation and university applications.
Since then I have been working as a freelancer basically a technical trainer who gives technical workshops at different colleges. I have also written three technical books for Apress publications for which I get the royalty quarterly and beside this, I wrote a few paid articles with some organisations.
So, how should I justify all this in DS-160 current employment section?